# How do I append a DataFrame while using a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe, twitter

I'm trying to fetch tweets for different dates and appending them into a dataframe and finally writing into a csv file. The text file appends the tweets but the df gets overwritten and so does the csv file.

## Here is my code :

```
import datetime 
x= datetime.date.today()
y= x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
c= datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
d= c.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
e= datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=2)
f= e.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
g= datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=3)
h= g.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
i= datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=4)
j= i.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
k= datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=5)
l= k.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
m= datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=6)
n= m.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
o= datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
p= o.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

a=[p,n,l,j,h,f,d]
b=[n,l,j,h,f,d,y]
for i in range(len(a)): 
    data = Cursor(api.search, q, since=a[i], until=b[i]).items()
    tweet_data = []
    # current_working_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    current_working_dir = "./"
    log_tweets = current_working_dir + '_tweets.txt'
    with open(log_tweets, 'a') as outfile:
        for tweet in data:
            tweet_data.append(json.loads(json.dumps(tweet._json)))
            outfile.write(json.dumps(tweet._json))
            outfile.write("\n")
            
    print "text file written"
    # Create the dataframe to be used
tweets = pd.DataFrame()
tweets['Tweet'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['text'].encode('utf-8'), tweet_data)
tweets['Dates'] = map(lambda tweet: time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.strptime(tweet['created_at'],'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')), tweet_data)
tweets['User'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['user']['screen_name'], tweet_data)
tweets.to_csv("string.csv", sep=",", index=False)
    
print " String CSV written......"
```

My CSV file is being overwritten for each consecutive date. I've tried to append dataframe but failed.

Answer (score 3):

The default mode for Pandas to_csv is write, which will overwrite the file.  The proper way to append would be:

`tweets.to_csv('string.csv', mode='a', header=False, index=False)`

Also set header to False so that it is not added again

Comment: it works brother. Thanks, But since it doesn't contain any header, can you tell my how to add header WITHOUT explicitly making a column name list and assigning it to header using col_name.